# Is this 10 pack real?

Tags: physiology, bodybuilding

I saw [this video where a guy shows he has a 10 pack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-s-F4AGEIZ0). Then in the comments people explain the human body only has 8 ab muscles. Some claim the bottom two muscles are implants.

[image]

Can this be real, or does he actually have surgically implanted fake bottom abs? I'm curious to know if its really possible.

Comment: See also [8 abdominal muscles but 10 pack](https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/52531) on Biology.SE

Comment: I've always understood the N-pack to refer to horizontal bands, so that would be a 5-pack.

Comment: @jamesqf but the bottom 4 each seem to have a vertical crease in the center rather than being a horizontal band.

Comment: Seems plausible that this might be done with [synthol](https://www.quora.com/What-is-synthol-and-how-is-it-used-in-bodybuilding).  If you search for synthol and bodybuilding, there're tons of pictures of crazy body shapes achieved with it.  Dunno about a 10-pack of abs, but seems like a reasonable possibility; two of the abs would just be from the oil.  The other 8 might be as well, or they could be real, or partially real.  The coloration in that photo looks suspicious, though, so it could also be Photoshop.

Comment: @Nat Oh wow yeah it could maybe be that. Not photoshop though because in the video you can see them clearly.

Comment: @Viziionary: Yes, the normal ab muscle does have a crease in the middle, though seldom as pronounced as the ones in that picture.

Comment: @jamesqf my point was, it seems like the horizontal bands you're talking about dont seem to (from what Ive googled) have creases in the middle like what we see in the picture.

Answer (score 4):

**Possibly real, but not "10 (or even 8) 'ab muscles'"**

The appearance of compartmentalized 'ab muscles' is due to an anatomical structure called the [abdominal linea alba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linea_alba_(abdomen)).

It is common for there to be three 'tendinous intersections' (on each side) which create the classic 'six-pack' appearance -- however, [studies of cadavers](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4525496/) indicate that, due to genetic variations, four or even five are possible; [a different study](http://dro.dur.ac.uk/9507/) found again that three was most common, but noted that two or even just one was also possible.

Again, these are genetic variations and having a 10-pack is **not** indicative of superior physical fitness compared to those mere mortals who can only muster an 8-pack.

Comment: *"but noted that two or even just one was also possible."* I knew it.